# I need to add a destroy function for decline option in my follow request page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to rails and I am creating a app in which a clone like twitter. The users are connected with each other by sending request first and the corresponding user accepts or deletes the request. I followed michael-hartl book.

User model:

```
attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :id

has_many :reverse_requests, foreign_key: "requested_id", class_name:  "Request", dependent: :destroy
has_many :requesters, through: :reverse_requests, source: :requester

has_many :requests, foreign_key: "requester_id", dependent: :destroy

has_many :requested_users, through: :requests, source: :requested
```

Accept or decline view:

```
   <ul class="users">
     <% @users.each do |user| %>
       <%= link_to gravatar_for(user, size: 30), user %>
       <%= link_to user.name, user %>

//Accept which invokes create

       <%= form_for(current_user.relationships.build(follower_id: user.id)) do |f| %>
         <%= f.hidden_field :follower_id %>
         <%= f.submit "Accept", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
       <% end %>

//Decline which invokes destroy

       <%= form_for(user.requests.find_by_requested_id(current_user),
             html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %>
         <%= f.submit "Decline", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
       <% end %>
     <% end %>
   </ul>
```

Requests controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:request][:requested_id])
  current_user.request!(@user, 2)
  #current_user.status!(2)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to @user }
    format.js
  end
end

def destroy
  @user = Request.find(params[:id]).requester
  current_user.decline!(@user)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to current_user }
    format.js
  end

end
```

When decline is clicked the request is removed from the database as well as from the user requests list. Which I need it also after accepting the request it should be removed from both the database and request list.

Can anyone help to achieve this?

Is it possible to call the destroy function after the accept button is clicked?

Or any other suggestions??

Comment: What is your `decline/accept` logic? That will help me to write better answer for you.

Comment: Accept finds requester_id of current user and creates a relationship in table using .create! method. Decline similarly destroys the requester_id from the request table

Answer (score 0):

Answering to your question, YES we can call the destroy action. But I suggest we go with something more scale and pretty design, here is my rough design (not tested):

```
# routes.rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :requests, only: [] do
    member do
      patch :accept
      patch :decline
    end
  end
end

# request.rb
class Request < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  def accept
    # 1. Do accept logic
    # 2. Destroy
    destroy
  end

  def decline
    # 1. Do decline logic
    # 2. Destroy
    destroy
  end
end

# requests_controller.rb
class RequestsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_request

  def accept
    @request.accept
    # Redirect somewhere
    redirect_to profile_path
  end

  def decline
    @request.decline
    # Redirect somewhere
    redirect_to profile_path
  end

  private

  def set_request
    @request = Request.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

With the following design you and add more logic easily to `decline/accept` e.g send email ...